# How many pixels wide is a pinned tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pixels

I'd like to know how many tabs I can pin into a single browser window on my 1280 x 800 px Chromebook, but I want to use math-magic to find out instead of just pinning a bunch of tabs and counting them.

Comment: Going to depend on browser sized, how small is small enough, pixel density, just depends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im gonna say 50 pixels wide. I used the mac digital color metre.

Comment: Hmm, it might actually be different across OSes. I've got 12 pins taking up ~2/5 of my 1280, maybe 500ish pixels.

Comment: ah well that may be true, try using a similar utility to count number of pixels

Comment: Giving you the check so maybe you get a badge for correct answer on a question with a million downvotes :-p. I really was curious about this! Being on a Chromebook I haven't got a lot of utilities to figure this stuff out.